# Click button open other page and scroll down

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Pressing the button on the first page should open the second page and the page should be scroll down. However, when another button on the first page is pressed, the page must be opened without scroll down. What should I do for it?

```
<button id="button1" class="button" onclick="window.location.href = page2">
<button id="button2" class="button" onclick="clickCommentButton();">
function clickCommentButton() {
        //rest of the code
        window.location.href = page2;

//productReviewSide is div id in Page2 HTML
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#productReviewSide").offset().top
        },
            'slow');
    }
```

Comment: try with # url `page2url#productReviewSide`, 
Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432927/click-button-open-other-page-and-scroll-down/#wmd-input here `wmd-input` is id of the comment textbox

Comment: As an example, it may be wrong, because the link is redirected to this page.

Comment: try opening the example URL in my first comment in a new tab - it will still focus on the comment box.
ref: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind it is quite simple, pass a parameter within the URL to distinguish between both events.

Check the following snippet

```
function clickCommentButton(){ 
            window.location.href = page2?isScroll=true ;
 }
```

On page 2 where scroll to bottom is required, write the following code in document.ready

```
if(getQueryString("isScroll") == 1){

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#productReviewSide").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}
```